# How to display toast like this in wordpress admin front side

Tags: php, wordpress

I added this code but it's not working and not showing error either in front of admin side

[image]

```
function sample_admin_notice__error() {
        $class = 'notice notice-error';
        $message = __( 'Irks! An error has occurred.', 'sample-text-domain' );
     
        printf( '<div class="%1$s"><p>%2$s</p></div>', esc_attr( $class ), esc_html( $message ) ); 
    }
    add_action( 'admin_notices', 'sample_admin_notice__error' );
```

Comment: This code looks fine I have tested it and works. please be specific about when and where you want to print this notice. otherwise, it will show you everywhere on the admin side.

Comment: I want all over admin to know admin have no data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code

```
   function general_admin_notice(){
        global $pagenow;
        if ( $pagenow == 'options-general.php' ) { //it is work pagewise 
             echo '<div class="notice notice-warning is-dismissible">
                 <p>This notice appears on the settings page.</p>
             </div>';
        }
    }
    add_action('admin_notices', 'general_admin_notice');
```

You want to display a notice only to users with the author user role.

```
function author_admin_notice(){
    global $pagenow;
    if ( $pagenow == 'index.php' ) {
      $user = wp_get_current_user();
      if ( in_array( 'author', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
          echo '<div class="notice notice-info is-dismissible">
          <p>Click on <a href="edit.php">Posts</a> to start writing.</p>
          </div>';
      }
   }
}
add_action('admin_notices', 'author_admin_notice');
```

Comment: This is working on function.php but I have to display it when clicking on button

Comment: There are two options for doing this 1) you can add a script between this code  and call onclick event & 2) you can code like this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/80215/how-can-i-add-a-jquery-onclick-event-to-the-publish-posts-button

Comment: this click function in another plugin files and I have to check from that file and when no data is found then I have to display admin_notice on the front side.

Comment: I have one PHP file and that file I have one condition and If that condition called else part then I have to display admin_notice

Comment: here is the code which I write
 `$myVar = false;
if($myVar == true){

}else{
    add_action('admin_notices','call_notice');
}
function call_notice(){
    echo '<div class="notice notice-error is-dismissible">
    <p><b style="font-size:15px;">You are Called.</b></p>
    </div>';
}`